# how to stop ubuntu from making sounds for every key i press

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, voice

I'm using ubuntu 14 that from some reason announce on every key that is pressed. I don't know how someone did it, but i would love to know how to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried entering "xset -b" in a terminal prompt ?